# How generate video mp4 from array png with appsScript Google

Tags: google-apps-script, video, type-conversion

please help, i can't figure out how to create a video from an array, i use google appsscript and i don't understand how to do it.
So far I managed to get the array containing the pngs taken from the drive folder but after I can't convert it to mp4
I thank anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*It is not possible to generate a video with Google Apps Script*.

### Workaround

I would search in Google: `png to video online`